# prevent data.table from rolling for more than a certain number of periods in R

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to `roll` some values in `data.table` but prevent it from rolling for more than a certain number of periods.  I know this functionality is implemented in the latest R-Forge version, 1.8.7, but I would like to hold off upgrading until it is stable enough for CRAN. Ex:

```
require(data.table)
dtb = data.table(id=1, thedate=c(1,3,100), val=c(1, 2, 3), key=c("id", "thedate"))
dtb2 = data.table(id=1, thedate=1:100,key=c("id", "thedate"))
res = dtb[dtb2, roll=TRUE]
```

This roles the value 2 very far. I would like to stop it from rolling after N periods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

v1.8.7 isn't on CRAN not because it's unstable as such but because CRAN maintainers' time is limited; package maintainers have been asked to reduce the frequency of submissions to CRAN.

If you need the limited `roll` feature then there is no better way than upgrading to v1.8.7, afaik.  You can save the current R-Forge .zip, or use the copy I placed on the homepage. If there is a problem it's easy to revert to 1.8.6.

Since the limited `roll` feature is new it would be great if you tested it, since you need it.  Otherwise releasing to CRAN doesn't add anything really, other than an artificial line in the sand.